# I would like to localize my constants. Constants are defined and declared the usual way:

Tags: ios

```
extern NSString * const kStringName;

NSString * const kStringName = @"Whatever...";
```

How to make it localizable? This just can not work...

```
NSString * const kStringName = NSLocalizedString(@"Whatever...", @"Whatever...");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [String Constant as a Localized String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581675/string-constant-as-a-localized-string)

Comment: A complete tutorial on Localization :http://www.ibabbleon.com/iphone_app_localization.html

Answer (score 0):

Answer is in your question already. Constant can not be localized, because it is made as constant string at compile time.

Don't use constants.